# TIC-TAC-TOE in C++

Tags: visual-c++

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void drawBoard();
void startGame();
void player2();
void limit();
char turn;
char turn1;
char board[9] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' };
void main()
{
    cout << endl << "                          *** TIC-TAC-TOE ***" << endl
        << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "**Start the game please**\n" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\tPlayer 1 <x> - Player 2 <o>" << endl << endl;
    drawBoard();
    limit();
    system("pause");
}
void drawBoard()
{
    cout << "The playing board is here for you!!" << endl << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
}
void startGame()
{
    int choice;
    int cell = 0;
        turn = 'x';
        if (turn == 'x')
        {
            cout << "Player's 1 turn [x]: ";
        }
        else if (turn == 'o')
        {
            cout << "Player's 2 turn [o]: ";
        }
        cin >> choice;
        cout << "enter the cell number: ";
        cin >> cell;
        if (choice == 0 && board[cell] == '0')
        {
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << turn << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 1 && board[cell] == '1')
        {
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << turn << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 2 && board[cell] == '2')
        {
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << turn << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 3 && board[cell] == '3')
        {
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << turn << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 4 && board[cell] == '4')
        {
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << turn << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 5 && board[cell] == '5')
        {
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << turn << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 6 && board[cell] == '6')
        {
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << turn << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 7 && board[cell] == '7')
        {
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << turn << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 8 && board[cell] == '8')
        {
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
            cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
            cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << turn << endl;
            cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "This cell number is already used! Enter the number again.";
        }
}
void player2()
{
    int choice;
    int cell = 0;
    turn1 = 'o';
    if (turn1 == 'x')
    {
        cout << "Player's 1 turn [x]: ";
    }
    else if (turn1 == 'o')
    {
        cout << "Player's 2 turn [o]: ";
    }
    cin >> choice;
    cout << "enter the cell number: ";
    cin >> cell;
    if (choice == 0 && board[cell] == '0')
    {
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << turn1 << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 1 && board[cell] == '1')
    {
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << turn1 << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 2 && board[cell] == '2')
    {
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << turn1 << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 3 && board[cell] == '3')
    {
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << turn1 << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 4 && board[cell] == '4')
    {
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << turn1 << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 5 && board[cell] == '5')
    {
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << turn1 << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 6 && board[cell] == '6')
    {
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << turn1 << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 7 && board[cell] == '7')
    {
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << turn1 << "  |  " << board[8] << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 8 && board[cell] == '8')
    {
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[0] << "  |  " << board[1] << "  |  " << board[2] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[3] << "  |  " << board[4] << "  |  " << board[5] << endl;
        cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
        cout << "  " << board[6] << "  |  " << board[7] << "  |  " << turn1 << endl;
        cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "This cell number is already used! Enter the number again." << endl;
    }
}
void limit()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        startGame();
        player2();
    }
}
```

It works but I am facing some difficulties. I can't restore the board while everey player's turn. How would I restore values?

Answer (score 0):

Just update the board after every move

```
board[choice]=turn;
```

And then display the board.